# Neo4jException when exporting json file from neo4j database

Tags: php, database, graph, neo4j

How does one convert a `neo4j` database to a json file using PHP?

I tried this:

```
$queryx = ":POST /db/data/transaction/commit {statements:[{statement:MATCH n RETURN n, resultDataContents:[graph]}]}";
$resultx = $client->sendCypherQuery($queryx)->getResult();
file_put_contents ("data/charlize.json", $resultx);
```

But it generated this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Neoxygen\NeoClient\Exception\Neo4jException' with message 'Neo4j Exception with code "Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax" and message "Invalid input ':' in C:\wamp\www\PhpProjectNeo4j1\vendor\neoxygen\neoclient\src\Extension\AbstractExt‌​ension.php on line 88

I do not understand why my code would generate this error, and how to get past it to accomplish my goal of exporting the `neo4j` database to a json file.

Comment: What errors did it generate?

Comment: ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Neoxygen\NeoClient\Exception\Neo4jException' with message 'Neo4j Exception with code "Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax" and message "Invalid input ':' in C:\wamp\www\PhpProjectNeo4j1\vendor\neoxygen\neoclient\src\Extension\AbstractExtension.php on line 88

Comment: You should include those in your question!

Comment: I think my method won't work. So I look for a method which work fine.